# What's the shortcut to open the "Insert Function" dialog?

Tags: microsoft-excel, shortcuts

I'm typing a function in a cell in Excel and I want to choose the arguments by hand. What's the shortcut to bring up the dialog menu entitled "Function Arguments" that appears when I click the "fx" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> is the shortcut for insert function, at least on Windows and Excel 2007

Comment: I confirm this is also the case for Excel 2013 (running on Windows 8.1).

Comment: I use this all the time now.

Comment: @Robino F2 lets you edit a cell. Also I recently learned something I didn't even know which is F4 will cycle through relative, absolute and mixed references.